# How to define a variable which gives the last inserted character of the current buffer?

Tags: buffers, insert

Is there a built-in variable which gives the last inserted character of a buffer (inserted by self-insert-command)?
Note that the cursor is not necessarily at the place of the last insertion.

If there is not such a variable, any other solution for defining a variable which determines this character would be helpful.

Comment: I doubt there's such a variable, however it should be trivial to achieve with a `post-command-hook` that tracks the argument if `this-command` is `self-insert` and checks for `this-command-keys` to figure out what key was hit to insert the character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution implementing what I've suggested in my earlier comment:

```
(defvar my-last-inserted-character nil
  "Last character inserted, buffer-local.")
(make-variable-buffer-local 'my-last-inserted-character)

(defun my-update-last-inserted-character ()
  (setq my-last-inserted-character (concat (this-command-keys))))

(add-hook 'post-self-insert-hook 'my-update-last-inserted-character)
```

It would be better to wrap it up in a minor mode before anyone gets the idea to package this.

Comment: After inserting `x` I evaluate the expression `(if (eq '(my-last-inserted-character) ?x) (message "yes") (message "no"))` but it shows "no", maybe I miss something here.

Comment: First, it's a variable, second, it's a string. You'd need to do `(if (string= my-last-inserted-character "x") (message "yes") (message "no"))`.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much for this nice solution.

Comment: Name: Note that this works when typing keys which call `self-insert-command`, but not for anything else. If this still answers your question, you might like to edit the question itself to clarify that the requirement is not as general as it currently sounds.

Comment: @phils Thanks for your remark and precision.  I edited the question accordingly. I am also interested to know about other approaches to the problem which can applied for the cases other that `self-insert-command`.

Comment: Name: I suspect that the `after-change-functions` variable is the way to go, for the more general case.

Answer (score 1):

Would `last-command-event` in `post-self-insert-hook` do what you want?

e.g.:

```el
(add-hook 'post-self-insert-hook (lambda () (print last-command-event)))
```

Comment: Thanks, This shows the ascii code of the inserted character.